# Why don't ANSI symbols work in PuTTY/Debian?

Tags: putty, character-encoding, node.js, tree

The awesome application `tree`, which I installed in Debian with `apt-get install tree`, has the option of drawing its output using ANSI graphics. Its output looks like this now:

```
.
tqq node_modules
x   tqq coffee-script
x   tqq eco
x   tqq express
x   tqq forever
x   mqq stylus
tqq package.json
mqq src
    mqq daemontest.coffee
```

This is obviously wrong. These are my `LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8` and `LC_ALL=C` env variables. PuTTY is set to expect UTF-8 as well. If I change PuTTY to "Use font encoding" then `tree -A` looks right, however `npm list` will then break and look like this:

```
â”œâ”€â”€ coffee-script@1.2.0
â”œâ”€â”¬ eco@1.1.0-rc-3
â”‚ â””â”€â”€ strscan@1.0.1
â”œâ”€â”¬ express@2.5.5
â”‚ â”œâ”€â”¬ connect@1.8.5
â”‚ â”‚ â””â”€â”€ formidable@1.0.8
â”‚ â”œâ”€â”€ mime@1.2.4
â”‚ â”œâ”€â”€ mkdirp@0.0.7
â”‚ â””â”€â”€ qs@0.4.0
...
```

All of this stuff should work correctly, so I'm guessing my settings are wrong somewhere. Could anyone help me tune in on exactly where?

---

EDIT: My `env` now looks like this. Problem is still there

```
root@chu:~# env
TERM=putty
SHELL=/bin/bash
SSH_CLIENT=**Censored**
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
USER=root
LS_COLORS=rs=**Removed because wall of text**
PYTHONBREW_ROOT=/usr/local/pythonbrew
MAIL=/var/mail/root
PATH=/usr/local/pythonbrew/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/root
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LS_OPTIONS=--color=auto
PYTHONPATH=:/root/pymodules
LOGNAME=root
SSH_CONNECTION=**Censored**
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first problem is that **you have $LC_ALL set to `C`**. If you set $LC_ALL, it will *override all other locale settings*, including $LANG. Since the "C" locale uses ISO-8859-1, `tree` will not know about Unicode availability and will attempt to switch to the VT100 graphics codepage (there are four switchable codepages), which PuTTY refuses to do when expecting UTF-8. To fix this, **stop setting LC_ALL in your environ** and `tree` will use Unicode graphics.

The second problem is that **your $LANG variable is incorrect** – you don't need to specify the charset twice. Set **`LANG=en_GB.UTF-8`** to fix this.

The third problem is that you are *forcing* `tree` to use VT100 graphics. **Do not use the `-A` option.**

Keep PuTTY configured for UTF-8 as well.

(`npm` is unaffected by this because it is *hardcoded* to use Unicode graphics regardless of locale.)

Comment: Hey thanks for a brilliant answer, but I have a few problems with it. First of all, I've never touched the LC_ALL or LANG variables. I don't know where they're set and I don't know how to unset them or change them. Could you elaborate just a bit on that? Thanks!

Comment: @Codemonkey: Check your shell startup scripts first. If you are using *bash*, then `grep LC_ALL ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_login ~/.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/*bashrc /etc/environ* /etc/default/locale` -- copy/paste that :)

Comment: Yeah I found the LC_ALL declaration as well at the LANG one. I removed the LC_ALL and edited LANG. The env output is edited into my question, because tree still just writes "tqq" and "mqq" instead of ANSI graphics

Comment: @Codemonkey: 1) Are you running `tree` or `tree -A`? Do *not* use the ANSI mode; just run `tree` and let it use Unicode instead. 2) Does `locale -a` show `en_GB.UTF-8` in the list?

Comment: `locale -a`: http://pastebin.com/Kzttvgm2. But why can't I use the ANSI characters? `npm` can use them, why can't tree?

Comment: @Codemonkey: You need to generate the locale data, then; in Debian `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` should work, or you can manually uncomment the "`en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8`" line in /etc/locale.gen, then run `sudo locale-gen`. And like I already said: **`npm` does *not* use ANSI graphics. It  uses their Unicode (UTF-8) equivalents, and only that.**

Comment: Note that PuTTY is somewhat unusual in not supporting the [ANSI/VT100 graphics in UTF-8 mode](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/utf8-plus-vt100.html). Xterm and others such as Cygwin's mintty do support both at the same time.

Comment: So to summarize, the problem is with `tree` because it can't display UTF-8 ANSI-looking graphics like `npm` can?

Comment: @Codemonkey: `tree` *can* display UTF-8 graphics, but you're telling it not to. **1)** Make sure you have your locale settings correct; "`locale -a`" must have `en_GB.utf8` in the list. **2)** Set your $LANG to `en_GB.UTF-8`. (Yes, $LANG must end with `UTF-8`, not `utf8`.) **3)** Do *not* run "`tree -A`"; just "`tree`" will suffice.

Comment: Here is my working setup:  http://sprunge.us/VSSc

Comment: [Here is my not working setup](http://pastebin.com/g5nb5qWF). Technically all your requirements are being met, but I do have some errors popping up. Notice that `tree` is using ASCII symbols only, not pretty UTF-8 graphics. Can you see why?

Comment: @Codemonkey: The errors are saying that `en_GB.UTF-8` *does not exist* on your system. I already told you how to add it -- either a) run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` and enable the locale, or b) manually edit `/etc/locale.gen`, uncomment the required line, then run `sudo locale-gen`.

Comment: Oh god, my bad. I thought I had already done that, but I had the en_US locale installed, not the en_GB. It works now. Thanks a lot for your help