# Why can't bash display symbols like æ, ø and å?

Tags: linux, debian, putty, character-encoding, utf-8

I have a file I've called æøå.js (just an example), and when I run `ls` in the directory where it's stored I get

```
root@chu:~/projects/someproject/server# ls src
a.js  b.js  ??????.js
```

So it seems such symbols can't be displayed. PuTTY is set to expect UTF-8, and my `env` looks like this

```
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
USER=root
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LS_OPTIONS=--color=auto
PYTHONPATH=:/root/pymodules
LOGNAME=root
_=/usr/bin/env
```

(I've removed some stuff from that output since they can't possibly be relevant anyway)

But here's the thing; When I open a file with `vim` then I can type and see all those symbols without a problem. So the problem is apparently just in the shell/bash. Are there any settings I can supply that will allow bash to display those symbols? Can someone also explain why it doesn't work now, with UTF-8?

---

Edit: This is how `tree` displays æøå.js

```
|-- src
|   |-- a.js
|   |-- b.js
|   `-- \303\246\303\270\303\245.js
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I already explained, *twice,* in our [earlier discussion](https://superuser.com/questions/378122/why-dont-ansi-symbols-work-in-putty-debian/378126#378126), the problem is that your locale configuration is pointing to a nonexistent locale.

Your environment including $LANG is okay; however, the `en_GB.UTF-8` locale must be generated.

On most distributions (including Debian):

1. Open `/etc/locale.gen` in a text editor.
2. Uncomment the `en_GB.UTF-8` line by removing the leading `#`.
3. Run `locale-gen` as root.

On Debian:

1. Run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` as root.
2. Scroll down to the "`en_GB.UTF-8`" entry, mark it with <kbd>Space</kbd>.
3. Select `OK` with <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

Also, for the record, `ls` is a separate program; it is *not* part of bash.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't think this question was related. Also I asked this question before you solved my previous one :-) `ls` displays the symbols correctly now and I'll mark your answer as correct. `tree` however, working correctly in every other way, displays the file as `\303\246\303\270\303\245.js`. Is that fixable?

Comment: *That* might depend on the version of `tree`, actually. I compiled [1.6.0](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/src/tree-1.6.0.tgz) (latest) and 1.5.3 (Debian squeeze) on the same system, and 1.6.0 displays Unicode while 1.5.3 uses octal.

Comment: Good catch. I installed version 1.6.0 and it displays everything correctly. Thanks a million once again for your help! :-)